# Animate an skewed div without undesired effects

Tags: html, css

I was thinking to make a menu with parallelogram containers and animate them on CSS. The idea is when you hover an item, the parrallelogram change it's height to make a visual scaling effect.

So far, so good, but the problem is that when I change the parallelogram's height on hover, it also change it's position a little bit to the right and I don't know why.

So the cuestion would be: Is it any way to change the parallelogram's height preserving it's position?

Here's the undesired effect I've got:

```css
.container {
    float: left; 
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.parallelogram {
 position: relative;
 width: 125px;
 height: 50px;
 -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
 -moz-transform: skew(-30deg);
 -o-transform: skew(-30deg); 
 transform: skew(-30deg); 
    transition: all .4s linear;
}

.parallelogram:hover {
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parallelogram" style="background-color: red;">
    1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="parallelogram" style="background-color: green;">
    2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="parallelogram" style="background-color: blue;">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, you just need to change the `transform-origin` for `.parallelogram`.

Here's the updated demo.

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}
.parallelogram {
  position: relative;
  width: 125px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-30deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-30deg);
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  transition: all .4s linear;
  transform-origin: top right;
}
.parallelogram:hover {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parallelogram" style="background-color: red;">
    1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="parallelogram" style="background-color: green;">
    2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="parallelogram" style="background-color: blue;">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```